# Cosa vuol dire "stangare" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nella commedia *Sotto paga! Non si paga!* di Dario Fo (testo aggiornato nel 2007 e pubblicato da Einaudi) ho letto:

> APPUNTATO     No, non c’era nessun pericolo! Guardi qua... (*mostra un sacchetto*) Sono sacchi pieni di zucchero raffinato, farina di grano duro e riso fino e integrale, quelli!
>   Tutta merce proveniente dalla Cina, attraverso i Paesi
>   dell’Est e la Jugoslavia.
>   
>   LUIGI E GIOVANNI (*in coro*)     Certo! Senza controllo e senza
>   rispettare le leggi di mercato! 
>   
>   LUIGI     A meno che non gli capiti di ribaltarsi per strada. 
>   
>   GIOVANNI     Beh, un dio che **stanga** i furbi c’è sempre... un dio cinese!

Non capivo il significato di "stangare", quindi l'ho cercato sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00000080.jpg) (ho l'impressione che sia il vocabolario più completo, che include di solito i diversi sensi figurati di un termine). Tuttavia, non sono sicura di averci trovato nessuna accezione che abbia senso nel contesto del brano. Forse "colpire  duramente  infliggendo  una  pena 
morale"?

Ho cercato in rete e ho trovato un altro [testo](http://www.centroreginadellapace.it/html/dettaglio_relazione.php?id=113) che parla di Dio che "stanga":

> Questo era il patto dell'Alleanza, dato a Mosè; invece il popolo d’Israele continuamente tradisce Dio e si dà all’idolatria. Ad un certo momento, Dio prima manda i Profeti a richiamarli, i Profeti vengono trattati male, non vengono ascoltati e vengono uccisi e ad un certo punto Dio, **stanga**. Gerusalemme fu distrutta, il Tempio fu distrutto, tutti vengono deportati in Babilonia per settant’anni. Il Signore poi si commuove e li fa ritornare. Poi di nuovo, dato il loro comportamento, li punisce; questa è la storia dell’Antico Testamento.

Quindi, il significato in questi testi sarebbe semplicemente "punire" o "punire duramente"?

Comment: Penso sia importante sottolineare il senso letterale, da cui deriva la “spietatezza” del senso figurato.

Comment: D'accordo, @Gio, grazie!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stangare, sia in senso letterale che figurato, fa riferimento ad una punizione e o ad un evento implicitamente duro o molto pesante.

[Stangare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/stangare/) da Treccani.it:

> **Percuotere con una stanga**: *dichiarò d’essere stato stangato da alcuni suoi avversarî di gioco*. **Più comune in senso figurato, colpire duramente**, soprattutto con imposizioni o richieste o infliggendo perdite di denaro: *ci stangheranno bene con le tasse, quest’anno!; ci si mangia bene, in quel ristorante, ma come stangano!; ho accettato di fare qualche mano di poker, ma mi hanno stangato.*
>
> Con altro significato,  *stangare un alunno, stangare un candidato agli esami*, giudicarlo negativamente, dandogli pessimi voti; meno comune, infliggere una dura sconfitta, in competizioni sportive.